# Selecting the union part of an sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query

```
SELECT
    L.Account,
    L.PaidOffDate
FROM 
    MARS.dbo.vw_Loans L
WHERE
    L.isActive = 'False'
    AND L.LoanStatus NOT LIKE '%REO%'
    AND L.LoanStatus <> 'Trailing Claims'
)
UNION
-- loan numbers for REO sold
(
SELECT
    L.Account,
    R.SoldDate
FROM 
    MARS.dbo.vw_REO R
LEFT JOIN 
    MARS.dbo.vw_Loans L ON L.ConvertedToPropertyID = R.PropertyID
WHERE
    R.Active = 0
    AND R.Status = 'Sold'
    AND L.isActive = 'False'
    AND L.LoanStatus LIKE '%REO%'
)
```

I put this as a common table expression, how do I select R.SoldDate in that case?

Specifically I am trying to run this

```
CASE 
   WHEN Inactives.PaidOffDate IS NOT NULL 
        AND Inactives.PaidOffDate BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @reportingDate), -1) AND @reportingDate
      THEN Inactives.PaidOffDate 
      ELSE 
         CASE 
            WHEN Inactives.SoldDate IS NOT NULL 
                 AND Inactives.SoldDate BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @reportingDate), -1) AND @reportingDate 
               THEN Inactives.SoldDate 
               ELSE ''
         END 
END AS [CHECKING PIF DATE]
```

But I cannot select `Inactives.SoldDate`

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking here. The values for R.SoldDate will be found in the column named PaidOffDate.

Comment: I don't follow what you're asking. What CTE? When you "Union" data (using the `UNION (ALL)` operators) you can't then request only rows from a specific dataset in the union clause; not unless you had a way of identifying said dataset. Once all the data is unioned, `R.SoldDate` has no context; it is simply `PaidOffDate` (I assume, probably `CTE.PaidOffDate`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are after here is a computed column, something like this:

```
SELECT
    L.Account,
    L.PaidOffDate,
    'Payoff Date' AS Type
FROM MARS.dbo.vw_Loans L
WHERE
    L.isActive = 'False' AND
    L.LoanStatus NOT LIKE '%REO%' AND
    L.LoanStatus <> 'Trailing Claims'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    L.Account,
    R.SoldDate,
    'Sale Date'
FROM MARS.dbo.vw_REO R
LEFT JOIN MARS.dbo.vw_Loans L
    ON L.ConvertedToPropertyID = R.PropertyID
WHERE
    R.Active = 0 AND
    R.Status = 'Sold' AND
    L.isActive = 'False' AND
    L.LoanStatus LIKE '%REO%';
```

The computed column `Type` keeps track of the origin of each record, so that you will know this after the union has been peformed.  Note that I switched to `UNION ALL`, assuming that you always wanted to retain all records.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the values into separate *columns* rather than separate *rows.  I think the logic you want is conditional logic:

```
SELECT L.Account,
       (CASE WHEN L.LoanStatus NOT LIKE '%REO%' AND L.LoanStatus <> 'Trailing Claims'
             THEN L.PaidOffDate
        END) as PaidOffDate
       (CASE WHEN L.LoanStatus LIKE '%REO%'
             THEN R.SoldDate
        END) as R.SoldDate
FROM MARS.dbo.vw_Loans L LEFT JOIN
     MARS.dbo.vw_REO R 
     ON L.ConvertedToPropertyID = R.PropertyID AND
        R.Active = 0 AND R.Status = 'Sold'
WHERE L.isActive = 'False';
```

The other possibility is that you actually want two separate CTEs, one for each part of the query.